# django-social-auth redirect after login

Tags: django, django-socialauth

After google's login, I want to be redirected to my page. This is what I do

```
<a id="google-login" href="/login/google/?next=/static/index.html">Google</a>
```

But still I get redirected to

```
/accounts/profile
```

How can I make django socail auth redirect me to the page I need?

This is my django-social-auth configuration:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

I tried adding at the top:

```
'myapp.views.redirect_to_such_and_such',
```

Didnt work.

Again, how can I make django socail auth redirect me to the page I need?

Thanks in advance.

Jenia

Comment: Did you look at here; http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=redirect

Comment: nice. thanks a lot. you can post this as an answer so that I'll accept it

Comment: Jenia...how did it worked out ?

Comment: @JeniaIvanov can you mark my answer as "accepted"? thx

Answer (score 9):

Set this:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'url_you_want'
```

Answer (score 3):

if anyone had this problem in the future, apply this code after url tag tamplate `?next={{ request.GET.next }}` example `href="{% url "social:begin" "linkedin-oauth2" %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}"`

Comment: I think this is solution better, since you can dynamically redirect wherever you want.